# Undefined variable async JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I just started out learning Node.js / Express and I still have difficulties with the Asynch functions. I made some functions to interact with a postgresql database (with some tutorials), and selecting rows from data is going fine but for some reason something is going from with deleting the rows. Here is an example of a function that is going well:

```
const getPlayers = () => {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM Players ORDER BY p_id ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
    resolve(results.rows);
  })
 }) 
}
```

Now the following function is not going well. Console.log(id) gives the right number, but it seems that id is undefined when executing the query and I suspect that it has to do with Asynch/synch. Now Asynch is new for me, so I am also not an expert on what is going wrong.
Here is the function that is nog going good:

```
const deletePlayer = (id) => {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  pool.query('DELETE FROM Players WHERE player_id = ?' , [id], (error,results) => {
   if (error) {
    reject(error)
   }
   resolve(`Player deleted with ID: ${id}`)
   })
  })
 }
```

The function call:

```
app.delete('/laProjects/:id', (req, res) => {
players_model.deletePlayers(req.params.id)
.then(response => {
 res.status(200).send(response);
 })
.catch(error => {
 res.status(500).send(error);
 })
})
```

Comment: FYI it's "async" and "sync", no "h". Also, I don't see any `async` in your code (with or without "h"), so how are you getting that error?

Comment: Is it a problem of `deletePlayers` vs `deletePlayer`?

Comment: the code looks valid. did you just delete the same value multiple times ?

Comment: Sorry, deletePlayers / deletePlayer are good in the code, I just changed the function names for this questions so it would be more easy to read!

Answer (score 0):

#### How to debug this situation

Don't automatically assume it is an async issue. First try some simple console.log steps:

```
const deletePlayer = (id) => {

console.log("Started deletePlayer with id: ",id)   ///////////

 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  console.log("Inside the promise, id is the same, namely: ",id) ///////////

  pool.query('DELETE FROM Players WHERE player_id = ?' , [id], (error,results) => {
   if (error) {
    reject(error)
   }
   resolve(`Player deleted with ID: ${id}`)
   })
  })
 }
```

#### See if 'id' is what you expect it to be

If you *don't* see any console.log messages printed, maybe, as @steve16351 suggests, you are editing `deletePlayer` but actually calling another function`deletePlayers`?

#### In general, avoid using the word "async" for promises used without the "async" keyword

When Promises first arrived in Javascript, they were *the* practical tool for asynchronous programming, so people sometimes used the term "async" for them in speech.

However since the `async` keyword arrived, it is better not to use the word "async" for things that are not that keyword.

#### Simple glossary

*Blocking code*: a program that simply waits (preventing any other code running) while some external process happens.

*Callbacks*: the oldest form of asynchronous programming in JS. You tell JS to run a certain function only after some external event has happened.

*Promises*: a more convenient and readable way to achieve the same effect as callbacks. You can imagine the process to be constructed out of hidden callbacks.

*`async` keyword*: an even more convenient and readable way to achieve the same effects as callbacks and promises. It is implicitly made out of promises, although it protects you from having to think about how to construct a new promise.

#### In response to you reporting that id is 5 inside the promise

This tells us that your original assumption, that the error is due to a variable being undefined, is incorrect. `id` has the expected value.

Therefore the error is that the API is giving an error in response to this call:

```
pool.query(
  'DELETE FROM Players WHERE player_id = ?' , 
  [5], 
  (error,results) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error)
    } else {
    resolve(`Player deleted with ID: ${id}`);
    }
  }
)
```

So why don't you run exactly that, in simplified form like this:

```
pool.query(
  'DELETE FROM Players WHERE player_id = ?' , 
  [5], 
  (error,results) => {
    console.log("Error:",JSON.stringify(error,null,2),"Results:",JSON.stringify(error,null,2))
  }
)
```

This sends an explicit request to `pool.query`, and explicitly reveals the output. I don't know the format the `pool.query` API is expecting: perhaps it is not quite right?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering the question. The problem is not deletePlayer/ deletePlayers, I quickly changed the function names for this question so it would be easier to read. I did these console.logs and the answer is always correctly. Running your code gives me: "Inside the promise, id is the same, namely:  5" but I get an error code: 42601